# Search single Document with Textfield in Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, textfield

I am trying to get one piece of document inside my collection with a textfield input and a button click to search.
I can get it to work when I put the name inside  let docRef = db.collection("Airports").document("exactname")

but I have to replace it with a variable for the textfield.
What could be the approach for that ?

FirestoreManager.swift:

```
import Firebase
import SwiftUI

class FirestoreManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String = ""
    @Published var elevation: String = ""
    @Published var runway: String = ""
    @Published var searchairport: String = ""

    init() {
        fetchRestaurant()
    }

    func fetchRestaurant() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        let docRef = db.collection("Airports").document(searchairport)

        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("error", error ?? "")
                return
            }

            if let document = document, document.exists {
                let data = document.data()
                if let data = data {
                    print("data", data)
                    self.name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
                    self.elevation = data["elevation"] as? String ?? ""
                    self.runway = data["runway"] as? String ?? ""
                }
            }

        }
    }   
}
```

ContentView.swift:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase


struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var firestoreManager: FirestoreManager
  
   
      
    var body: some View {
       
        
        TextField("Enter Airportname", text: $searchairport)
        
        Text("ICAO: \(firestoreManager.name)")
        Text("Elevation: \(firestoreManager.elevation)")
        Text("Runway: \(firestoreManager.runway)")

            .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(FirestoreManager())
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to [perform a query on Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)?